# How to create the live App Icon like Apple Clock using flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

**Dynamic App Icon In Flutter**

I am expecting for a way to make a similar ui,Put it in the app icon.
want to create the live app icon continuously changing itself, like apple clock app icon shows the current time in the App Icon.

Is There is any way to make that type of App icon in flutter

[Similar App Icon like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FJYi.gif)

Comment: it is only possible for ios. And also for that you have to use different assets for each app icons. https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/dynamically-change-the-app-icon-7d4bece820d2

Comment: Is there is any way to done in flutter for android.

Comment: with quick google search I found this for android https://medium.com/@simonmisles/dynamic-launcher-icon-and-name-for-android-e40bf0561715

Comment: I need in flutter

Comment: that's native stuff there are no plugins right now. and I checked more about that android article. There is one comment which states that after updating icon you won't be able update your app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243673/discussion-between-kumaresan-jackie-and-pokaboom).

Answer (score 0):

-- you can use animated svg file to create this types of gif

-- go to this website and create your needed icon and use.

https://svgator.com/

-- this is a example for this animated svg

https://app.svgator.com/editor#/f706ead3c59448878a5673ac2b95c1da